# Can state change occur based on expressions involving properties?

Tags: qml

Is it correct to change the state based on property changes.

For example:

```
ListView {
        id: settinglist
        model:netOptionsModel
        focus: true
        delegate: listDelegate;
        state:activeFocus ? listActive:listInActive // Is this valid
        ....
}
```

Is the above code valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to change the state based on property changes.

Yes, it is.

It is a common way out there to change properties dynamically, called "binding". `state` is not an exception in here.